# Angular UI-Router redirect logged in user away from login route

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router

I am working on a Angular + Meteor project with the ui-router.
My issues is that when people are logged in and manually go to the `/login` route, I want to redirect them directly to the home page.

I don't want to do this in the controller but directly in the route. I tried onEnter function, but that doesn't have the $meteor dependency at hand to see if the user is logged in.
So then I got to `resolve` (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve).

With this I created a working solution, however it feels partly like a hack and I would love some feedback or suggestions on how to remove the hacky part.

The route Code (in coffeescript):

```
.state( 'public.login',
    url: '/login'
    views:
      "container@public":
        templateUrl: 'client/views/session/login.html'
        controller: 'SessionCtrl'
    resolve:
      'currentUser': [ '$meteor', '$state', ( $meteor, $state )->
        $meteor.waitForUser().then( ( user )->
          if user
            $state.go( 'private.home' )
        , ( error ) ->
          console.log("error", error)
        )
        return
      ]
  )
```

As you can see that instead of passing on the promise as return of the `resolve` function, I check the promise myself and if user is logged in, I do a state change back to Home.

This works, but it feels like I am hacking the resolve function.

I don' want to add a listenter to the `stateChangeError' as situated in the example 8.5 @ http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular1/user-accounts-authentication-and-permissions.
There they catch the error if the resolve promise is false, in my case I do the opposite and only want to relocate when the promise is true.

Any suggestions?

***update****
Added this solution based on suggestion by Nikhil. Thanks for this!

```
angular.module( 'myApp' ).run(
  ( $rootScope, $location, $state ) ->
     $rootScope.$on( '$stateChangeStart', ( event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams ) ->

     if toState.name is 'public.login'
       if event and event.targetScope and event.targetScope.currentUser
         #to prevent login view to be displayed, I prevent default
         event.preventDefault(); 
         $state.go( 'private.home' )
     )
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can move your logic in following block

```
$rootScope.$on( "$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
     // logic

});
```

Comment: This is what I am doing in my app. You can put this code in a service and inject the other application components you need (eg. to find out if the user is logged in or not). Plus since it's now in a service, you can write unit tests for it.

Comment: I did as you suggested and I see in the event object within the rootScope object the currentUser object resolved. I will do my check there. Would that be the best implementation?

Comment: @Mattijs - Yes. I believe so.